# Shiny app with filters for categorical and numerical data

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a dataset with categorical and numeric variables.

My data looks like this

```
     Region        Country Project.ID            Client   PG Percent.of.CoE Status
1         Africa          Sudan       1001          Vodafone PG 1             50 Signed
2         Europe         Russia       1002   Vodafone Russia PG 2             50    Low
3        Europe  United Kingdom       1003            Orange PG 3             50 Signed
4  Latin America           Peru       1004 Co-operative Bank PG 3             50 Signed
5           Asia       Malaysia       1005       AB Malaysia PG 2             14 Signed
6         Europe         France       1006            Orange PG 4             50   High
7         Africa   South Africa       1007        Coris Bank PG 1             40 Signed
8           Asia          China       1008         Gulf Bank PG 2             50    Low
9  North America  United States       1009               ABI PG 1             50 Signed
10        Europe        Germany       1010                O2 PG 2             50 Medium
11 Latin America      Argentina       1011              ACEP PG 3             40    Low
12 North America         Canada       1012 BCN United States PG 1            100 Signed
```

[The sample data is stored here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u39mz3e0o1l249c/pg1.csv?dl=0)

What am I trying to do with this data? 
I want to create a simple app, which with filter categorical and numeric variables.
My current UI looks like this and this is my desired UI.
[image: My current UI looks like this and this is my desired UI.]

The first filter works perfectly. The second does not due to data structure.

Trying to resolve it, I changed tha data format, using gather, see the code below. As a result my data looks like this.

```
Percent.of.CoE variable             value
1              50   Region            Africa
2              50   Region            Europe
23             40  Country         Argentina
24            100  Country            Canada
25             50   Client          Vodafone
26             50   Client   Vodafone Russia
47             40       PG              PG 3
48            100       PG              PG 1
49             50   Status            Signed
50             50   Status               Low
```

I am not sure that it is correct format for this. But any solution will work.

My code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)

# Global code

# Read file on a local machine
data_pg <- read.csv("pg1.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Transform into tidy data, removing long/lat variables. 
data_pg_df3 <- data_pg %>% select(Region, Country, Client, PG, Status, 
Percent.of.CoE) %>% gather(key = "variable", value = "value", - 
c("Percent.of.CoE"))

# UI code

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
            titlePanel(h1("Test", align = "center")),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                           selectInput("dataInput", "Choose to filter by:",
                                       choices = c("Region",
                                                   "Country",
                                                   "Client",
                                                   "PG",
                                                   "Status"),
                                       selected = "Choose to display by"),
                           sliderInput("percentInput1", "Percent of CoE", min = 0, 
                                       max = 100, value = c(0, 0))
              ),


              mainPanel(

                # Output
                tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                            tabPanel("Plot",  plotOutput("plot", height = 850)))
                )
              )
            )


#  Server code
server <- function(input, output) {

# 1. Select among columns
selectedData <- reactive({
filter(data_pg_df3, variable == input$dataInput)
}) 

output$plot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(selectedData(), aes(x = value, fill = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "count") + theme(axis.title = element_blank())
})
```

**HOW TO WRITE THE SECOND FILTER?** I did. **But wrong and might be wrong filtering too.** But I think my dataframe is not good for this.

```
 # # 2. Select among percents
 # selectedPercent <- reactive({
 # filter(data_pg_df3, Percent.of.CoE >= input$percentInput1[1] & 
 Percent.of.CoE <= input$percentInput1[2])
 # })
 # 
 # output$plot <- renderPlot({
 # ggplot(selectedPercent(), aes(x = value, fill = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "count") + theme(axis.title = element_blank())
 # })


}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to filter by variable and then to filter by percent, leaving only projects withing selected range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with your data structure. Try something like the following:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

# 1. Select among columns
filtered_data_1 <- reactive({
filter(data_pg_df3, variable == input$dataInput)
}) 

filtered_data_2 <- reactive({
filter(filtered_data_1(), Percent.of.CoE == input$percentInput1)
}) 

output$plot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(filtered_data_2(), aes(x = value, fill = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "count") + theme(axis.title = element_blank())
})
```

The key thing is to pass one reactive to another. Alternatively you could apply both filters within the same reactive:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

# 1. Select among columns
filtered_data <- reactive({
    data_pg_df3 %>%
        filter(variable == input$dataInput)
        filter(Percent.of.CoE == input$percentInput1)
}) 

output$plot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = value, fill = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "count") + theme(axis.title = element_blank())
})
```

This can be done using your original data structure in a variety of ways. For example, you could just filter on `Percent.of.CoE` and then pass the column given by `input$dataInput` to your ggplot aesthetic.

Comment: Simon, both options do not work for me. The first one leads to a grey area instead of barplot, the second - Warning: Error in filter: object 'Percent.of.CoE' not found. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I also think that with sliderinput() we need to chose between two values, it is a range of numbers

Answer (score 1):

I resolved also.
My server looks like this. In general, I was right and the answer above is correct too.

```
#  Server
server <- function(input, output) {


# 1. Select among columns
selectedData <- reactive({
  filter(data_pg_df3, variable == input$dataInput) %>%
    filter(Percent.of.CoE >= input$percentInput1[1] & Percent.of.CoE <= input$percentInput1[2])

 }) 

 output$plot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(selectedData(), aes(x = value, fill = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "count") + theme(axis.title = element_blank())
 })

}
```

The tricky part for me was with UI.

Instead of

```
sliderInput("percentInput1", "Percent of CoE", min = 0, 
                                       max = 100, value = c(0, 0))
```

I put

```
sliderInput("percentInput1", "Percent of CoE", min = 0, 
                                       max = 100, value = c(1, 99))
```

This resolved my problem. Works perfectly now. 
And as I mentioned before, I use sliderInput with values, because I needed to select a range of data.